# How use another database and session to authorization?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm building a Asp.net MVC3 aplication (with Razor) and I have a Data Base that have information about users and roles.

This is simplified scheme of my DB.

User(**IDUser**, Login, Password);
Role(**IDRole**, Name);
UserInRole(**IDUser**, **IDRole**); //Many to Many

Looks like this:

[image: db schema screnshot]

I read about use AuthorizeAttribute, to control pages for loged users, and with specific roles and I research about use My DB to control users and roles. So my questions is:

1. Is possible use my DB to manage users and roles and use [Authorize] in my actions? [If yes how i do that?]
2. Is possible use session in the place of cookie to manage login and use the Authorization native Asp.net MVC3? [if yes, how i do that? if no how use session otherwise?]

If possible please post code examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Pedro. Based in your post I build this to use SESSION:

```
public class CustomAutorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public List<string> Roles { get; set; }

    public CustomAutorizeAttribute()
    {
    }

    public CustomAutorizeAttribute(params string[] Roles)
    {
        this.Roles = new List<string>();
        this.Roles.AddRange(Roles);
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        User user = (User)httpContext.Session["user"];

        if (user != null)
        {
            if (Roles != null)
            {
                foreach (var role in user.Roles)
                {
                    if (Roles.Exists(e => e == role)) return true;
                }
                return false; // User don't have any hole
            }
            else
            {
                return true; // The Attribute is used without roles.
            }
        }
        else return false; // Not logged.
    }
}
```

Post here to hope others.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but you want to use the `[Authorize]` attribute to work with your custom users database?

If that's the case, there are somethings to check:

To simply allow/deny based whether the user is authorized or not, the stock `[Authorize]` attribute will work just fine. The custom logic goes in your Login action, where you will check the database with the given credentials and issue the cookie accordingly. Something like:

```
    public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
    {
        bool isValid = //check the database with the given username and password

        if(isValid)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);

            return RedirectToAction("...");
        }else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

If you want to also control access based on roles, I would say there are 2 immediate ways:

- Implement a custom Membership and Role providers, something I don't like as I find them pretty useless, and always end up redoing the logic in my respositories
- Implement a custom AuthorizeAttribute, like

  ```
  public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
  {
      protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
      {
          //Check based on these 2 properties:
          //  this.Roles
          //  this.Users
          //against httpContext.User

          //return true or false to indicate access or deny 
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks it was very hopefull. But i have one more question FormsAuthentication works with Session or Cookie?